# How to create dynamic table using Accordion in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Unable to display table using accordion in react native and it can only fetch string (in my case) and displaying [object object] for table

The link which I have referred

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mrcluc/react-native-accordion

Want to display a table which is create on loop by fetching JSON data in React native using Accordion and works for scrollview.

Comment: Hi Sana, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you include the relevant code that you wrote into the question? Otherwise people attempting to help you can only make blind guesses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordion is only suites for text and not for tables at all, so please refer  https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-seperator-headref, https://www.npmjs.com/package/accordion-collapse-react-native, 
here you can add table in the body section (even by referring JSON file directly).